# История браузера. Как определить длительность между переходами по ссылкам?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

**ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ**
    1. Открываем ССЫЛКУ 1
    2. ПАУЗА
    3. Открываем ССЫЛКУ 2

**СЦЕНАРИЙ**
    ВАР 1.
    1. Извлечь из истории браузера время посещения ССЫЛКИ 1 и ССЫЛКИ 2.
    В данном случае:
     - ССЫЛКа 1 -  10:41
     - ССЫЛКа 2 - 10:43
    2. Вычислить разницу между временем посещения
     10:43 - 10:41 = 2 мин

-или 
    (смотря как проще сделать)
    43 - 41 = 2 мин
    3. Поместить в ячейку
        a. **ВАР 1**
            i. DataGridView ().
        b. **ВАР 2**
            i. Таблицу table  (table = new DataTable())

**ВОПРОС**
    1. Как реализовать данный сценарий?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем конкретно у вас сложность? Ведь по сути сценарий у вас расписан же. Просто берете, получаете доступ к истории браузера, оттуда записываете её в какой-то свой класс, где будут поля или свойства для ссылки и времени посещения. Потом высчитываете разницу во времени между 2-мя соседними ссылками, результат записываете в DataTable или DataGridView. 

А делается это так - берется и пишется код, который выполняет действия, обозначенные в сценарии.

Comment: получаете доступ к истории браузера - вы имеете ввиду спарсить? Потом высчитываете разницу во времени между 2-мя соседними ссылками -  как выполнить вычитание для 10:43 - 10:41 ? @ BlackWitche

Comment: Возможно и спарсить, или попросить Selenium прочитать историю и отдать ее вам, если он так может, конечно.